# How to avoid paste of multiline text on ubuntu command line?

Tags: command-line, security, paste

This question may sound weird. But here is what happened and I'd like to find out the ways to avoid this happening again.

I accidentally pasted contents of a text file into SSH CLI on Ubuntu 16.04. The machine was used for my production setup. I actually copied contents of a log file and intended to paste it in a nano editor opened in some other SSH window, but mistakenly pasted it on command line interface. The shell attempted to process every line as a command and created some junk files in local directory.

This fortunately didn't cause much damage however I want to know **is there any way to avoid the accidental paste on Ubuntu command line?** Or can I disable the command line for multiline inputs?

I use PAC ssh client to connect to my remote systems.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PAC, however maybe you can implement something equivalent to this? [Prevent accidental execution of commands in Linux if pasting text containing one or more return characters](https://serverfault.com/questions/731022/prevent-accidental-execution-of-commands-in-linux-if-pasting-text-containing-one)

Comment: That's precisely what I am looking for. Will check if something like that possible for PAC or any other SSH clients on Ubuntu.

Comment: You might want to google *"bracketed paste"* as well - see for example [prevent multi-line paste in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202732/prevent-multi-line-paste-in-bash)

Comment: You can remove all line breaks from your clipboard before pasting by xclip -o | tr -d \\n | xclip

Answer (score 3):

Bracketed paste may be what you need. Assuming you are running a terminal that supports it (e.g., xterm, putty, gnome-terminal), and assuming you are running the bash shell, all you have to do is execute this command in each terminal:

```
set enable-bracketed-paste
```

You can even put this command at the end of your .bashrc. From that moment on, any stuff you *paste* into the shell will not be immediately executed, even if it contains newlines. However, if you paste one or more lines and then hit 'enter' manually, all of the lines will be executed - so if you pasted something by mistake and don't want it executed, you must hit 'Ctrl-C' instead of 'enter'.

Caveat 1: bracketed paste will also be enabled for any programs you run in the shell. Many programs don't understand it. So if you run `cat` and then paste the word `hello`, you will see `^[[200~hello^[[201~` instead. This may not be what you want.

Caveat 2: some programs, such as `vi` or `emacs -nw`, will *disable* bracketed paste after they finish running, even if it was turned on before they ran. You could work around this by enabling bracketed-paste with every prompt. One way to do this would be to redefine `$PS1` to include the escape sequence `$'\e[?2004h'`. This may be a bit esoteric.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended on original [bracketed paste mode](https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste) post,

**On zsh** (with Oh-my-zsh) you can use the [**safe-paste** plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/pull/1698), which is already enabled by default (`ls  ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins | grep safe-paste`).

**On Bash** [set `enable-bracketed-paste`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1251430/349837), [seems to be since v4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44507798/4970442).

See also:

- https://lifepluslinux.blogspot.com/2017/01/look-before-you-paste-from-website-to.html
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39118/how-can-i-protect-myself-from-this-kind-of-clipboard-abuse